# Will an iOS app be available during transfer

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to transfer an app to another team, and the app is currently available in the App Store. During the transfer, will the app still be available for download through the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! It will remain available at all times!

There will be no "transition period" from the user experience side, even search won't be affected.

*You: "...but I understand that there will be a period when the transfer is still pending"*

Nothing, non-stop, it's a very seamless process.

According to Apple:

**Can I transfer my app to another account?**

> Yes. Use App Store Connect to transfer qualifying apps to another
>   account in case of an acquisition, asset purchase, or other similar
>   situation. When you transfer an app, it will remain available on the
>   App Store or Mac App Store, all ratings and reviews will carry over,
>   and users will continue to have access to future updates. To learn
>   more about transferring apps, sign in to App Store Connect.

Answer (score -1):

Yes

> When you transfer an app, it will remain available on the App Store or Mac App Store, all ratings and reviews will carry over, and users will continue to have access to future updates.

Learn more from [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I know it will remain available after the transfer, but I understand that there will be a period when the transfer is still pending, and was wondering if the app will be still available during that time.